# three.js matrix multiplication not working as expected

Tags: three.js

So I have a Matrix4() called 'transform' which has already had some operations applied to it. I can chain multiple rotations and translations and it appears to work ok. But then I then want to apply  this one last rotation and just can't get it to work. I am using the following code. The value of position at (A) and (B) and (C) are the same. Why is no rotation being applied? I have tried rotating on the various x,y,z axis. I'm not sure if I have a bug in the code or my expectation is incorrect.

EDIT: What I am really after is what the final x,y,z of the translated/rotated point is. I thought that would come from setFromMatrixPosition but maybe its something else?

EDIT2: Tried:

```
let position = new THREE.Vector3();
position.applyMatrix4(transform)
```

This is not getting the result I'd expect for the rotation I've done.

This is the basic code (I'm using Typescript)

```
  // Get the position from the current transform matrix.
  let position = new THREE.Vector3();
  position.setFromMatrixPosition(transform);   <===== A

  // Create a matrix to do rotation of -90 degrees on the z axis.
  let rotateTransform = new THREE.Matrix4();
  rotateTransform.makeRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(0, 0, MyHelper.ConvertToRadian(-90)));

  // Apply the rotation
  transform.multiply(rotateTransform);

  // Get the position again. Should be different result to above 
  position.setFromMatrixPosition(transform);  <===== B

  // Try a different approach
  let transform3 = new THREE.Matrix4();
  let quat2 = new THREE.Quaternion();
  quat2.setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(MyHelper.ConvertToRadian(-90),0 , 0));
        transform3.compose(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0), quat2, new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
  transform.multiply(transform3);
  absPos.setFromMatrixPosition(transform);  <====== C
```

Answer (score 0):

`position.setFromMatrixPosition(transform)` will just copy the position elements of the matrix into the `position` variable. What you need to do is multiply the matrix with the vector to do the complete translate/rotate.